# touchtouchEnded is not getting called after touchesBegan and touchMoved

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, events, touchscreen

I am having a strange effect with touches. Sometimes when I swipe the screen slowly the touchBegan and touchMoved get called but not the touchEnded, which kinda screws up my view movements. How is it possible that touchEnded doesn't get called? And my finger leaves the screen without running off the sides or anything like that !!
Any tips or suggestions to explain this behaviour? I really need the touchEnded to clean up my view.

Thank you for any advice.
Al

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you got a call to `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` in those cases without `touchesEnded:withEvent:` being called. Did you implement that method?

Comment: Indeed. In the iPhone programming video course on iTunes there is a guest talk by an Apple engineer all about the touch events. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I implemented the touchCancelled:withEvent also and it is not called. Is there any other reason why an event might get cancelled or deleted or not sent???